# Back button in the Detail view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm struggling with "Master-Detail" concept and almost everything works as expected except one little(but important) nuance. What should I change on the storyboard to have Back button on Detail view(the right corner at the bottom on the screenshot)?

Thanks in advance.
[image: Storyboard]

Comment: ? What does it go back to, and in what situation?

Comment: @wain, back to the "Master" view in the iPhone mode.

Comment: Detail view contrtoller's navigation controller is missing something like this `navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem`

Comment: I'm having similar issue except in ipad mode. Once i hide master view by tapping on detail view, i cannot call back master view because there is no master view button (left button) on navigation bar. How did you resolve yours?

Answer (score 1):

This is an older question, but I just ran into the same thing.  The issue is you do not need the navigation controller at the bottom right. Since that is a new navigation controller it will not have a back button, because it only contains one item in its stack.

Remove the bottom right navigation controller and just segue directly to the view controller and that will do it.

Additional tip... to remove the navigation controller and preserve the view, delete the link from the navigation controller to the view, and delete the segue links to the navigation controller. Then recreate the segues directly to your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

So far don't get anything straight. If you want like just below screen then you have to hide your navigationItem backbutton in viewDidLoad like this

```
navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

Then in storyboard you have add a toolbar and set it's item title 'Back'. You can also set image for it.

Then drag an action from this item and write this line inside that action

```
@IBAction func fbfdb(_ sender: Any) {
     self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

You may get an warning but you will get your desire action

[image]

Storyboard

[image]

Comment: I didn't mean custom button at the bottom corner, I mean navigation(regular one) button in the View Controller which is at the right bottom on the screenshot.